# If a certain value appears at least once in a row, change the last value of the row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where there are multiple rows containing a certain value I want to find, but I want to change the last value of the row if the value appears at least once to something else. The first column of my dataframe is the ID number, followed by 10 rows containing data where the value I want to find could appear. The 12th row would simply be a 1 if the value appears at least once, and a 0 if the value does not appear at all in 10 columns.

I tried:

```
def evervalue(col):
    df.loc[comb4[col] == 'value', 'col_to_change'] = 1

for column in df:
    evervalue(column)
```

This changes the value of the 'col_to_change' column for some rows correctly but not for some, unsure why.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data you are using, and a desired output along with the explanation you already gave

Answer (score 0):

You describe two separate items

1. add a row that contains 0 or 1 if column contains value you are searching for
2. replace last instance of search value in a row

```
import numpy as np
# synthesize data noted in question
search = "magic"
last = "hit"
df = pd.DataFrame({**{"id":[i for i in range(10)]},**{f"col{i}":np.where(np.equal(np.random.randint(0,10, 10), 0), search, "") for i in range(10)}})

# add "12th" row where desired value has been found in column
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.equal(df.values, search).any(axis=0).astype(int)[None], columns=df.columns)])

# change text of last match found in a row
yp = xp = 0
for x,y in np.argwhere(np.equal(df.values,search)):
    if x > xp and yp>0:
        df.iloc[xp, yp] = last
    xp = x
    yp = y
df.iloc[xp,yp] = last
```

### output

```
 id  col0  col1 col2  col3  col4 col5  col6 col7 col8 col9
  0                                                       
  1                  magic            magic  hit          
  2                                                       
  3                                     hit               
  4                                               hit     
  5                                     hit               
  6 magic                  magic        hit               
  7                                                       
  8 magic magic                         hit               
  9                                                       
  0     1     1    0     1     1    0     1    1    1    0
```